# Java: Sonar compulsory constructor

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-analysis, static-code-analysis

We're using Sonar for code analysis. For classes something like this

```
public class Car {
  private Engine engine; 

  // getter setter for engine
}
```

we get errors such as

`Non-abstract classes and enums with non-static, private members should explicitly initialize those members, either in a constructor or with a default value.`

We usually serialize our objects with Jackson, so constructor is not used anywhere in our code. So why do I still need to write a constructor? Would it make sense to disable this rule?  [Rule Link](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1258)

Another thing, if I change code as below

```
private Engine engine = null;
```

The error is not thrown. By default, all Java references are assigned with a null value. Is this line fooling Sonar? Should this be a bug in Sonar?

Comment: Note it recommends *"**explicitly** initialize"*, so the implicit initialisation to null wouldn't count.

Comment: This is an issue of the original developer signalling "This is what I intend" (i.e. `null`) vs "I forgot to, or didn't bother to, set an initial value".

Comment: If the class is _only_ used by Jackson/other library through reflection, then you could add `//NOSONAR` or use the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation mechanism on the violating code with a comment mentioning _why_ you're ignoring the rule. This will document to others that instance variables aren't initialized explicitly by design.

Comment: Disabling the rule is a bit dangerous because other files with the problem (genuine) could get ignored too. Instead, use NOSONAR or exclude the class/package. You could also mark violations as [false-positive](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Frequently+Asked+Questions#FrequentlyAskedQuestions-False-PositiveandWon%27tFix).

Comment: @jonrsharpe @Jim Garrison You're right, explicitly assigning null values make sense.    
@Mick Mnemonic `//NOSONR` or `@SuppressWarnings` doesn't make sense. It'll ignore other errors too. 
@Vasan right, disabling rule is dangerous.

Answer (score 5):

Sonar has very opinionated ideas about what you should do to avoid defects. Here, their opinion is that you should be explicit about initializing instance fields. I assume their thinking is that adding " = null" shows that you meant to set the field to null and that it is not an oversight.

Adding many //NOSONAR in code shared by many developers is a poor practice, as doing so soon becomes a convention and defeats the purpose of using Sonar. I suggest simply submitting to Sonar and adding the initialization. Either that, or turn off the rule.